# Select elemets in artboard of 2Dimensions Flare on flutter

Tags: flutter, flare

Basic Flare artboard (2dimensions.com)

[image]

My question is how to select elements of artboard on Flutter once I have export the final animation, for example I want to create multiple shapes and when I select one show an specific action.